# div tag causes line break

Tags: html, css

When I want to make an element with div, it creates a space between the content and the border. (blue line). Using span causes the element to break, displaying the content outside the borders. 
http://i66.tinypic.com/23k4xsp.png
This is my CSS code:

```
#main1 {
margin-left: 40%;
background-color: lightgrey;
width: 20%;
border: 5px;
padding: 5px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: grey;
border-width: 2px;
text-align: left;
}
body {
text-align: center;
background-color: yellow;
font-family: "Arial";
}
```

And my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>BMI</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="main1">
        <h3>BMI calculator</h3>
        <form action="results.php" method=""post"">
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="man">Man<br>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="vrouw">Vrouw<br><br>
            Lengte:<br>
            <input type="text" name="lengte"><br>
            Gewicht:<br>
            <input type="text" name="gewicht"><br><hr>
            <button action="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there any workaround? I'm fairly new to webdesign, I couldn't find anything on the webz... Thanks

Comment: It's called `display: inline`. But you shouldn't use `div` when you want to show something inline. `span` is used for that.

Comment: As I mentioned, It doesn't work. That just makes it worse, beacuse the borders just float in the middle of the screen as 2 brackets, while the content is dumped somewhere to the left.

Answer (score 1):

The space (line blue) comes because the `<h3>` tag has a default `margin`. If you set it to `margin: 0` the space will  disapear.

```
h3{
  margin: 0;
}
```

Also, I cannot reproduce your line break: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8umq5781/).

Answer (score 0):

This is actually caused by the `h3` tag. The header tags by default come with a margin both above and below the element.

Try adding to your CSS:
`h3 { margin-top: 0; }`